# Pdf render locally but not on dev

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I want to view pdf file in browser and the following code work for me on localhost but not working on dev server any idea whats wrong with this.

Also I want to view this pdf file in new window/tab when some one click linkbutton in the grid view.

```
   protected void lnkBtn_grid_View_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
       {
        try
        {
            var fileName = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
            var normalTextByte=Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileName);
            var encryptedFile = MachineKey.Encode(normalTextByte, MachineKeyProtection.All);
           Response.Redirect("~/statementfilesviewer.aspx?filename=" + Server.UrlEncode(encryptedFile));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Error.Log(ex);
        }
    }

   private void ReadPdfFile(string filename)
    {
        string keyName = "";
        try
        {
            string prefix = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Environment"] + "/StatementFiles/";
            keyName = prefix + SessionFacade.DbId + "/" + _intArtistId + "/" + filename;

            IAmazonS3 client;

            using (client = new AmazonS3Client())
            {
                var request = new GetObjectRequest
                {
                    BucketName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BucketName"],
                    Key = keyName
                };

                string cwrFilePath;
                using (GetObjectResponse response = client.GetObject(request))
                {
                    cwrFilePath = @"~/PDFs/" + filename.Replace(" ", "_").Replace("-", "_");

                    if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath(cwrFilePath)))
                        File.Delete(Server.MapPath(cwrFilePath));

                    if (!File.Exists(Server.MapPath(cwrFilePath)))
                    {
                        response.WriteResponseStreamToFile(Server.MapPath(cwrFilePath));
                    }
                }

                if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath(cwrFilePath)))
                {
                    //Literal1.Text = " <object data=\"/PDFs/" + filename.Replace(" ", "_").Replace("-", "_") + "\" type=\"application/pdf\" height=\"600\" width=\"99%\" style=\"border: none;\"><embed src=\"/PDFs/" + filename.Replace(" ", "_").Replace("-", "_") + "\" type=\"application/pdf\" height=\"600\" width=\"99%\" style=\"border: none;\" /></object>";
                    Response.Clear();
                    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                    Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
                    //Response.WriteFile(cwrFilePath);
                    Response.WriteFile(Server.MapPath(cwrFilePath));
                    Response.End();
                }
                else
                    Response.Write("File does not exists.  Please contact to support team.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Response.Write("File does not exists.  Please contact to support team.");
            EmailingDal.SendEmail("File does not exists on S3 server.", keyName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Probably a file path error. What is your exception email showing for keyName?

Comment: *"not working"* is very vague... What is not working exactly? Do you get any errors, or is the output just not as you expected it? Please try to provide as much information as possible to make it easier to understand your situation / problem.

Comment: no error, no exception just navigate to statementfilesviewer.aspx without rendering pdf file

Answer (score 0):

```
response.WriteResponseStreamToFile(Server.MapPath(cwrFilePath));
```

This should be writing the file in response object which is a client side variable. From the code it looks to be a file created on server side and read or shown in client browser.

You may try using StreamWriter to directly write a file on the hosting server.